# Solving a general Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

For "normal" equations in one variable we have several techniques for solving equations, such as $\sin(5x) = 5\pi\cos(5x)$ or $\ln(x + 2) = 4$. However, imagine we have the following equations:

$\sin(5x + 2y) = 2x + 3y$
$\ln(x + y) = 4x - y$

Do techniques exist to solve them? I've taken a basic number theory course, and most of the time we dealt with linear or special nonlinear Diophantine equations. Is there any solution technique for, say, trigonometric equations in general? Or at least can we prove that solutions do/don't exist?

Any thoughts on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Special cases aside, there is no general method to approach Diophantine equations. Think of it this way: it took the mathematical community hundreds of years to solve $x^n+y^n=z^n$, which is just about the most natural Diophantine equation  in the world.

Comment: I find it odd that you cite $\sin5x=5\pi\cos5x$ and $\log(x+2)=4$ as Diophantine equations, since it is easy to show that neither one has a solution in integers. If $x$ and $y$ are integers, then $\log(x+y)$ won't be an integer, unless $x+y=1$, so that one is pretty easy, too. The only solution of $\sin(5x+2y)=2x+3y$ in integers is clearly $x=y=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You're right, I was in a rush and put the first equations that came to my head. For the most part, I meant polynomial equations in two or more variables, but I wanted to keep the question as general as possible to help anyone else around with the same idea.

Comment: Matiyasevich showed 40 years ago that there is no general technique for finding the solutions of (polynomial) Diophantine equations, or even for deciding whether or not there is a solution. Special cases is all we have.